# Recurring Statement that selects another if not in array

Tags: php, mysql, select, recursion

Trying to figure out how to have it select another if it has already been selected because I am trying to display a new table value every time so I need to store it in a session variable.

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE ID = '3'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
                if($row['type']="clickbank"){
                echo '
                 <a href="http://jimihen.'. $row['user'] .'.hop.clickbank.net" >'. $row[description] .  
                '</a>';
            }


            for ($i=0; $i < 200; $i++){
            if (!isset($_SESSION['os'])){
                $_SESSION['os'] = array();
            }
            if (in_array($row['ID'], $_SESSION['os'])) {
  $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE ID = '6' ORDER BY 
  RAND()
LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
        while($snow = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2))
        {
            $stang = $snow['ID'];
        }
}

else if ($i = 99){
    unset($_SESSION['os']);
}
else
{

        if($row['type']="clickbank"){
                echo '
                 <a href="http://jimihen.'. $row['user'] .'.hop.clickbank.net" >'. $row[description] .  
                '</a>';
            }
            $stang = $row['ID'];
            array_push($_SESSION['os'],$stang);
            break;
}
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is error

```
if($row['type']="clickbank"){
```

change to

```
if($row['type']=="clickbank"){
```